# How to delete react-native-image-crop-picker image from /storage/emulated/0/Pictures

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-image-picker

When the image is captured it saves two images, one original and the other compressed and gives the path of compressed image in `image.path`. How can I disable saving of any image in gallery, I just need the base64 to work with?

```
ImagePicker.openCamera({
  cropping: true,
  width: 300*3,
  height: 400*3,
  includeBase64: true,
  mediaType:'photo',
}).then(image => {
  console.log('received image');
  console.log(image)
})
```

The output is as follows:

```
cropRect: {height: 4128, width: 3096, y: 0, x: 0}
data: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ"
height: 900
mime: "image/jpeg"
modificationDate: "1581938243000"
path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/398da0f6-73ee-47ce-bfdd-8b0fa68312a5.jpg"
size: 353210
width: 675
```

Comment: Managed to solve? I have the same problem

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to do delete the saved images.
You can use fs package by doing

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
RNFS.exists(image.path)
.then(path => RNFS.unlink(path))
```

Plus, it also saves in tmp directory, so use this as well

```
ImagePicker.clean().then(..)
```